# why binding CollectionView to Window.Visibility does not work while binding to same bound property works for ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Below ItemsControl binding works and the toolbars in control are refreshed accordingly when the collectionview is refreshed. However Visibility binding does not work (even once) and the converter is never called. No errors in output-window.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <xpui:IEnumerableHasItemsToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IEnumerableHasItemsToVisibilityConverter" />
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ToolbarContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Move to top" Click="MoveToTopClick" />
        <MenuItem Header="Move to left" Click="MoveToLeftClick"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <xpui:MenuItemToToolbarConverter x:Key="menutotoolbarconverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<ItemsControl Name="Toolbars" ItemsSource="{Binding GuiItemsInstance.FloatingToolbarsView}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource menutotoolbarconverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ToolbarContextMenu}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<Window.Visibility>
    <Binding Path="GuiItemsInstance.FloatingToolbarsView"  Converter="{StaticResource IEnumerableHasItemsToVisibilityConverter}"/>        
</Window.Visibility>
```

In GuiItems-singleton (GuiItemsInstance is property of the ViewModel) that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
    public CollectionView FloatingToolbarsView
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    }

    //I also tried to bind directly to FloatVisibility:
    private Visibility _floatVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    public Visibility FloatVisibility
    {
        get { return _floatVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _floatVisibility = value;
            // Sets the property value. Raises the PropertyChanged event, if needed.
            SetValue(ref _floatVisibility, value);
        }
    }

    ///Event of changes in underlying toolbar collection is handled like this
    private void RefreshFloatingToolbars(int RoleId)
    {
        ActiveRoleId = RoleId;
        FloatingToolbarsView.Refresh();

        if (ToolbarItems.Any(i => i.ToolbarLocation == ToolbarLocation.Float && i.RoleId == RoleId))
            FloatVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            FloatVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

The converter:

```
public class IEnumerableHasItemsToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (((IEnumerable)value).GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
//WindowViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged
public class FloatingToolbarWindowViewModel : WindowViewModel
{
    public GuiItems GuiItemsInstance { get; set; }

    public FloatingToolbarWindowViewModel(GuiItems guiItems)
    {
        GuiItemsInstance = guiItems;
        GuiItemsInstance.Host = Host;
    }
}
```

This does not work in any way, tried also binding to ItemsControl itself like this:

```
<Window.Visibility>
    <Binding Path="ItemsSource" ElementName="Toolbars"  Converter="{StaticResource IEnumerableHasItemsToVisibilityConverter}"/>        
</Window.Visibility>
```

which resulted in converter being called with value being null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `CollectionView` implements `ICollectionChanged`, which fires when an item in the collection has changed.  The `ItemsControl` looks for this event and reacts appropriately.  A "normal" control listens for `IPropertyChanged` notifications, which the `CollectionView` does implement, but won't fire for changes to the underlying collection. So your binding is never notified of changes.

You can "hook" the `CollectionChanged` event and send the appropriate `PropertyChanged` event with the binding, but at that point it's probably just easier to change the visible property yourself.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Naturally I have tried also to use property of type Visibility. That does not work either. get is never called.

Comment: I have also tried to change it directly in code behind. Nothing works so I'm intersted in this hooking, but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @matti Are you using MVVM or just straight up code behind (e.g. `MyWin.xaml.cs`) file?

Comment: I'm using MVVM. The bound property in singleton instance of GuiItems that is property of the ViewModel. Several ViewModels use this same instance.

Comment: thanks! now i saw ur edit, I try, but this is kinda thing i been doing, except that properties are not directly in viewmodel but in the singleton instance. however I tried also having them in viewmodel which didn't help. i just gotta iterate more! trial and error like all in wpf. nothing works as expected.

Comment: WindowVisibility-property's get is never called even when it's directly in ViewModel

Comment: pls remove the not working edit and i can accept your answer. Edit has multiple bugs if you try it. ur 1st answer is probably correct answer for questio why

Comment: "You can "hook" the CollectionChanged event" is not true due to inaccessibility of CollectionChanged.